# Java8 - nested data structure for multiple search criterias

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, time-series, maps

I am attempting to create a data structure for the following information, where I should have <1000 occurences (scalability would be very nice though):

- Time
- Server
- Stat
- Total

Where I can do queries such as:

1. What is the **TOTAL** for **STAT** by **SERVER**
2. What is the **TOTAL** for **SERVER** by **STAT**

My first guess (really ugly) would be a nested HashMap similar to

```
HashMap<Long, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>
```

What would be the best way to implement the above?
Am I missing the bigger picture and should redesign how I expect to store the data?

EDIT: An example use case would look like the following:

```
Time  | Stat   | Server  | Platform | Count
11:00 | Logins | Server1 | Android  | 10
11:00 | Logins | Server2 | IOS      | 5
12:00 | ERRORS | Server14| IOS      | 8
```

Comment: I'm thinking maybe guavas MultiMap  or googles Table could be useful

Comment: Maybe maintain a collection (such as a list) of custom objects, and have two maps for indexing it?

Comment: What does the `Long` represent as the first map's key? Could you give a small example data set maybe?

Comment: @daniu I've added an example data set, I don't think my initial  explanation fully covered it

Comment: Why use Java in the first place? Put this in a database, with sql can do these kinds of queries easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply store the individual items in an object, for example `DataPoint` which has the `time`, `type` (such as `login`)  and `platform`.

Then group them accordingly. If they are in memory you can even use `Stream`'s `groupingBy` `Collector` and do `counting()` to count all occurrences of each group.

So if you have `List<DataPoint> list` you could do:

```
Map<String, Long> countsByType = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataPoint::getType, Collectors.counting()));


Map<String, Long> countsByPlatform = list.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataPoint::getPlatform, Collectors.counting()));
```

I am not sure exactly how the `Long` of the time comes into the story, but if you want to group them by hour or something like that, you can do the same thing again before the above.

If `DataPoint` is going to already contain aggregates, like a `total`, you can replace `Collectors.counting()` with `Collectors.summingInt(DataPoint::getTotal)` or similarly `Collectors.summingLong()` if the values can get very large.

Comment: Thanks @jbx, I'm reading about `groupingBy` now. I will need to display the result in chart format. So having the POJO may make things a lot easier also.

Comment: Yeah I will need to output the data in chart format also, so the time is required.

Comment: the problem I see with your solution is that it counts the number of `DataPoint` objects. But I need to get all the `DataPoint` objects that match on 'platform' and then count all their 'totals'. Each 'DataPoint' will have a total for its relevant stat, e.g. number of logins for the matching `DataPoint`

Comment: If `DataPoint` is going to be an aggregate already, with `total` inside it, you just need to use `summingInt(DataPoint::getTotal)` instead of `counting()`